# Why are the columns stacked up?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am making a small shop and I have a page where I display my products. The code of this page looks like this:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){

        $id=($_GET['id']);

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){

            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

        }else{

            $sql_s="SELECT * FROM products
                WHERE productCode='{$id}'";
            $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
                $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);

                $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['productCode']]=array(
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "price" => $row_s['buyPrice']
                    );


            }else{

                $message="This product id it's invalid!";

            }

        }

    }

?>
    <h1>Classic Cars</h1>
    <?php
        if(isset($message)){
            echo "<h2>$message</h2>";
        }
    ?>
        <div class="container">

                <?php

                    $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC";
                    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/recent/item1.png" alt="">
                                <div class="overlay">
                                    <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                        <h3><a href="#"><?php echo $row['productName'] ?></a> </h3>
                                        <p>€<?php echo $row['buyPrice'] ?></p>
                                        <a class="btn btn-login" href="register.php">Add to cart</i></a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-login" href="register.php">Read more</i></a>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>

                <?php

                    }

                ?>
        </div>
```

Never mind the pictures, they are all the same at the moment.

The css of this part is as follows:

```css
#recent-works .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-3{
  padding: 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.recent-work-wrap img{
  width: 100%;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner{
  top: 0;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: .8;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner h3{
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner h3 a{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.recent-work-wrap .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;  
  padding: 30px;
}

.recent-work-wrap .overlay .preview {
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.recent-work-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The result of the code looks like this:

[image: Result]

Why are the columns stacked up? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Please show the generated HTML (in the browser right click -> show page source), not the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<img class="img-responsive inline-block" src="images/portfolio/recent/item1.png" alt="">
```

Add the below markup to your CSS:

```
.inline-block{ display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS property to image:

```
img{
display: inline-block;
float:left;
}
```